# Getting multiple results from map with "lens"

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

Having these imports:

```
> import Control.Lens
Control.Lens> import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

and a map value defined as follows:

```
Control.Lens Map> let m = Map.fromList [('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

I can get it's elements one by one like so:

```
Control.Lens Map> view (at 'b') m
Just 2
```

What I want to know is, having a set of keys such as this:

```
Control.Lens Map> import qualified Data.Set as Set
Control.Lens Map Set> let keys = Set.fromList ['d', 'c', 'b']
```

how to construct such a getter (I guess), using which I'll be able to get a set (or a list) of matching elements:

```
Control.Lens Map Set> view (**???**) m
[3, 2]
```

*Notice that the result contains only 2 elements, because there's no match for a key `'d'`.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following will work if you only want a getter over multiple fields.

First, you need to make Accessor from lens an instance of Monoid (that instance is in <del>in HEAD, but not released yet</del> **already defined in `lens >= 4`**, so you only need to define the instance if you're working with an old version of the library).

```
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Lens

instance Monoid r => Monoid (Accessor r a) where
  mempty = Accessor mempty
  mappend (Accessor a) (Accessor b) = Accessor $ a <> b
```

You can then use that instance to combine multiple lenses/traversals into a single traversal:

```
>>> import qualified Data.Set as S
>>> import qualified Data.Map as M
>>> import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
>>> import Control.Lens
>>> let m = M.fromList [('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3)]
>>> let k = S.fromList ['b','c','e']
>>> m ^.. foldMap at k
[Just 2,Just 3,Nothing]
>>> m ^.. foldMap ix k
[2,3]
```

foldMap uses the Monoid instance for Accessor and the Monoid instance for functions.

Comment: Accept this answer.  It's much better than mine.

Comment: Excellent! I felt it had to be simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the solution:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Monoid hiding ((<>))

empty :: (Applicative f, Monoid a) => (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)
empty _ _ = pure mempty

(<>)
    :: (Applicative f, Monoid a)
    => ((b -> f b) -> (a -> f a))
    -> ((b -> f b) -> (a -> f a))
    -> ((b -> f b) -> (a -> f a))
(l1 <> l2) f a = mappend <$> (l1 f a) <*> (l2 f a)
```

Example:

```
>>> toListOf (at "A" <> at "B" <> at "C") (M.fromList [("A", 1), ("B", 2)])
[Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]
```

The idea is that a `Traversal` is a monoid.  The correct solution would require newtyping the `Traversal`.

Edit: Here is the correct `Monoid` instance with all the newtype shenanigans:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable

newtype Combinable f a b = Combinable { useAll :: (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a) }

instance (Applicative f, Monoid a) => Monoid (Combinable f a b) where
    mempty = Combinable (\_ _ -> pure mempty)
    mappend (Combinable l1) (Combinable l2)
        = Combinable (\f a -> mappend <$> (l1 f a) <*> (l2 f a))

myMap :: M.Map String Int
myMap = M.fromList [("A", 1), ("B", 2)]

myLens :: Traversal' (M.Map String Int) (Maybe Int)
myLens = useAll $ foldMap (Combinable . at) ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Example:

```
>>> toListOf myLens myMap
[Just 1,Just 2, Nothing]
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution is very close. Is there a chance of any update to `myLens`, which will make `toListOf myLens myMap` emit a proper list as in what `catMaybes $ toListOf myLens myMap` currently will do?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I think so.  Give me a second to try to get it to work.