# Combining Getters into a Fold

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

In the spirit of the following questions:

- [Getting multiple results from map with “lens”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17144334/485115)
- [Combining lenses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17528119/485115)

I am now looking for a way to combine multiple [Getters](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Getter) into a single [Fold](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Fold.html), so that something like the following:

```
('a','b','c','d') ^.. (_1 <> _2 <> _3)
```

would result in this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But the code above actually fails with the following message:

```
No instance for (Monoid
                   (Accessor (Endo [Char]) (Char, Char, Char, Char)))
  arising from a use of `<>'
```

So how do I achieve this? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is also possible with the Monoid instance posted in this answer: [Getting multiple results from map with lens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156277/2494803)

```
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Lens

instance Monoid r => Monoid (Accessor r a) where
  mempty = Accessor mempty
  mappend (Accessor a) (Accessor b) = Accessor $ a <> b
```

Test:

```
*Control.Lens Data.Monoid> ('a','b','c','d') ^.. (_1 <> _2 <> _3)
"abc"
```

"abc" is just ['a','b','c'], so this does what you want.

(Update: Modern `lens` versions include this instance by default, so the second code snippet should just work out of the box.)

Comment: I could swear I tried this before posting the question and it failed. But after checking again now, it works. Must have messed up somewhere. Anyway, great, thank you!