# Haskell - Combine results from separate lenses

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

I'm trying to accomplish something like the following:

```
jsonStr = "{\"a\": \"hello\", 
            \"b\": [\"world\", \"everyone\", \"42\"]}"
someALens = ...
someBLens = ...
combinedJson = jsonStr ... someALens ... someBLens
```

to get as a result:

```
combinedJson == ["hello world", "hello everyone", "hello 42"]
```

However, the combination operators I've been finding (like `<>~`) seem to require a set value to mappend (or otherwise combine) over a lens.  How could I create a compound lens which can combine values from multiple lenses?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552835/combining-getters-into-a-fold is what you're looking for. Once you define the Monoid instance as described over yonder, you'll be able to write `combinedJson = jsonStr ^.. (someALens <> someBLens)`.

Comment: @haoformayor that monoid instance is _included_ in more recent `lens` releases. Just make `^.. (someALens <> someBLens)` an answer.

Comment: That was what I needed.  Thanks!  As soon as someone puts it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the answer is the rather-anticlimactic `jsonStr ^.. (someALens <> someBLens)`. Two getters mappend into a fold. Monoids, our friends forever.

Comment: How is this anticlimactic? I'd say it's rather beautiful in its simplicity!

Comment: Agreed - that's one of the reasons I keep coming back to Haskell.